# Breaking changes in jQuery 1.3.2 to 1.4.2

Tags: jquery

I have wasted an entire day trying to fix problems with my pages. After I realized that the pages stopped working when I moved from 1.3.2 to 1.4.2, I changed that line in my template, and my pages continued to work as before.

I have the greatest respect for the jQuery team and the library that they have created. I cannot for one moment therefore think that it is possible that the team would release a library that was not backward compatable AND not document it somewhere. Does anyone know where I can find that list - so that I dont get any nasty surprises in the event that I decide to upgrade sometime in the future?.

And for now, 'll just put the wasted day down to (an awful) experience.

Comment: Are you using any jQuery plugins? what functionality is breaking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always find the latest list of releases and release notes (including breaking changes) here:

- [jQuery.com Download/Release Section](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery)

For 1.4 specifically, [here's a list of breaking changes](http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14#backwards)